# Is there a key shortcut in Eclipse to place a cursor at the next occurrence of a highlighted selection?

Tags: eclipse

In Sublime and VScode you can highlight any section of text (a variable name, part of a string, parts of a loop or function) and then press Ctrl+D to place an additional cursor at the next instance of the highlighted selection that occurs in your code. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

To clarify: If I was viewing a file in VScode with an object like this

```
{
  read: true,
  reader: "jdoe",
  tread: none
}
```

and highlighted the "re" in read and pressed Ctrl + D twice I would get cursors before each instance of "re" like so

```
{
  |read: true,
  |reader: "jdoe",
  t|read: none,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If in ***Next Annotation*** the item ***Occurrences*** is selected, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** can be used to navigate to next occurrence:
  [image]
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>** to show/search occurrences in file, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** to navigate to next occurrence and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to transfer focus from *Search* view back to editor

Comment: This is a nice feature, so thanks for sharing it. It's not really what I am looking for. This only will navigate between recognized annotations. I want to place an additional cursor at an arbitrarily highlighted selection.

Comment: To jump to the next occurrence of the current or last selected string, hit Ctrl+K. Or what do you mean by _"an arbitrarily highlighted selection"_?

Comment: I added some clarification to the question if that helps. What I mean is any portion of a line from character x to character y without consideration for syntax, tokens, or any other part of the grammar or language. From "while(condition == true)" you could highlight "ile(cond" and place an ADDITIONAL cursor at the next occurrence of "ile(cond" each time a keyboard shortcut is entered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what @howlger suggested (Ctrl+K) will work for what you want. It should probably be in an answer, rather than a comment.